# protractor/selenium started ignoring the chrome options (chromeOptions) in protractor.conf.js

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I just rebuilt our development environment. This forced the latest version of chrome and suddenly the protractor based tests stopped working. After some research, I tracked this down to the fact that our chrome options in the protractor configuration file are now ignored.

Here is the configuration that used to work fine before:

```
exports.config = {
    ...
    multiCapabilities     : [
      {
        browserName: "chrome",
        chromeOptions: {
          args: [  
             "--disable-gpu",
             "--headless", 
             '--no-sandbox',
             "--incognito" 
         ]
          }
        },
      },
    ],
    ...
};
```

---

```
                     Before           After
protractor           6.0.0            6.0.0
selenium             4.0.0-alpha-1    4.0.0-alpha-1
chrome               74.0.3729.157    76.0.3809.100
chromedriver         74.0.3729.6      76.0.3809.68
```

Answer (score 4):

In recent versions of selenium you have to specify the chrome options as `goog:chromeOptions`. So just change the `chromeOptions` line above to the following:

```
...
       "goog:chromeOptions": {
...
```

and you are back in business.

Answer (score 2):

```
"chromeOptions": {}
```

its still usable in most cases, but does not support new arguments provided by chrome

suggested to use

```
"goog:chromeOptions": {}
```

Ref to doc: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

Same rule for firefox

```
"moz:firefoxOptions": {}
```

Ref to doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/firefoxOptions

Comment: I really do not see much difference between your answer and mine, you should consider editing mine instead, if you wanted to add the link.